# How to update GCP role binding for one account on GCP using IAM REST API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I can do the required operation using gcloud CLI:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding "${project_id}" --member="user:$email" --role="${role}" --condition="${condition}"
```

I would like to do the same operations, using IAM REST API. Examples could be found here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/cc9142e699f875650780e749d70e1a645313f4e2/iam/api-client/access.py

But none of them works with conditions.

How is it possible to do the same operation on Python using IAM REST API as with gcloud CLI?